# Add text to Action Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html.actionlink

Simple question:

Using `ActionLink`, how to create hyperlinks like these?

```
<a href="/Test"  
      class="dropdown-toggle"  
      data-toggle="dropdown">  
      Test
      <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

and

```
<a class="brand" href="/Home">
<img src="/images/w3r.png" width="111" height="30" alt="Fujiyama Logo" /></a>
```

I am trying to add a drop down using bootstrap. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to use `ActionLink` for this?  You're not linking to any actions...

Comment: Okay, I just added a link address.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use ActionLink in this situation. ActionLink is used to dynamically create a URL based on an MVC action and controller. The HTML itself should be fine in this example.

EDIT:

To use something more complex than just text with action links you can do the following. Please use the correct action and controller for the links:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Test")"  
      class="dropdown-toggle"  
      data-toggle="dropdown">  
      Test
      <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

and

```
<a class="brand" href="@Url.Action("Home")">
<img src="/images/w3r.png" width="111" height="30" alt="Fujiyama Logo" /></a>
```

Comment: If possible, can you please tell me how we can create such a link using ActionLink?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/V2#dropdowns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `<b class="caret"></b>` part of your link, but as for the creation of attributes, all you need to do is use the HtmlAttributes parameter of the `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` helper extension.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", new { }, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "dropdown-toggle" }, { "data=toggle", "dropdown" } })
```

This assumes you are attempting to create a link with the text `Test`.  The execution of this link will call the `Test` action on the `home` controller.

For creating the image link, you can create the link as per above and modify the css styling to include a background image (with appropriate padding).  You may even want to use a `:before` pseudo tag.

see http://dean-o.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/image-button-link-options-in-aspnet-mvc.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [FluentBootstrap](http://www.fluentbootstrap.com) which is a free and open source wrapper around Twitter Bootstrap for .NET code (full disclaimer: I am the developer).

It lets you write dropdowns like this:

```
using (var dropdown = Html.Bootstrap().Dropdown("Test").Begin())
{         
    @dropdown.DropdownLink("Test Link", "/Test")   
}
```

It also integrates with ASP.NET MVC to allow you to specify your links by action and controller or T4MVC to allow you to use `ActionResult`.